# Add border to text view adding by java coding in table layout

Tags: java, android, tablelayout

i have an acitviity with 2d array in its. I created table layout and added three textviews in it for three columns. I called for loop and now i could able to write all data of 2d array in table in three rows and 10 rows (10 is length of array). My question is can i give border to this table so that it looks like excel table with borders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use textView.setbackground() 
android passing a xml drawablefile

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke
        android:color="@color/colorAccent"
        android:width="1dp"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="5dp"/>


</shape>
```